# Type of adjective, "more" vs. "less"

Tags: english, terminology, adjectives

Does Linguistics group adjectives by their nature to denote an absolute quantity, as opposed to those that denote a relative quantity? If so, are there terms for such adjectives pointing out this particular division?

By absolute I mean that they have an inherent reference, as in "the distance from nothing", or "from zero". These would be adjectives like "large", "fast", or "high".
By relative I mean those without inherent reference, as in "small", "slow", or "low". Using those requires a reference, either by outright naming it, or by having context provide it.

Background: I want to explain why combining a multiplier with a "relative adjective" is at best unreliable to truthfully convey the correct scale. Or in other words: Why something like "three times smaller" (or "three times as small") is incomputable hogwash - for example, you couldn't plug "one" in instead of "three" and have this still make sense. It's either smaller or it isn't.

Some more background: To say something was small, you would have to have some sort of reference, a comparison, by which you could make that statement in the first place. Of course, you would also need that in "something is large", but 'large' can also quantify the property of the reference (its absolute size), and can then be used to describe something else: "B is 1 times larger than A" (meaning B is two times the size of A).
This quality of 'large', the ability to be used as a placeholder for an absolute is missing in 'small'. You cannot say "B is 1 times smaller than A" and have the listener be able to infer the correct 'formula' behind this statement to reliably arrive at the correct size of B, because the 'smallness of A' is never quantified. (Note that this irk is about non-colloquial usage where accurate conveyance, even across languages, is mandatory.)
It is this difference in quality that this question seeks to find terminology for.

Comment: Not sure why you think that there is no "implied reference, as in "small", "slow", or "low".

Comment: There are adjectives like _dead_ or _pregnant_ that 'do not admit of comparison', as the grammar books used to say; you're either dead or not, with no middle ground and no distinctions of _dead, deader, deadest_. But _large, fast,_ and _high_ take their implied reference from context, same as  _small, slow,_ and _low_. A small mountain is bigger than a large hill, for instance.

Comment: Do you mean something like the interval vs ratio distinction in statistics?

Comment: Maybe I should have said "inherent" instead of "implied". I'll amend the original and add some clarification.
Also, I'm not familiar with statistics enough to answer that.

Comment: No.  Linguistics is a field of study.  A linguist might or might not agree with you, but a field of study will not be able to have an opinion.

Comment: @GregLee So I should have used "Grammar" instead of "Linguistics"?

Comment: No, I don't think Grammar would be able to have an opinion, either.  Your question seems to me to be about the proper use of language, and this is not a matter that most linguists concern themselves with, since linguistics is mostly descriptive.  Linguists describe what people say, as opposed to what they ought to say.